# Spring-Data: What is the difference between Autowiring a @Service and Autowiring the Repository Directly

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, springsource

I am using Spring-Data-JPA and in my persistence tier use both Repositories to access the database and then sometimes use
1) the Service class with repositories within it, and then autowire the service 
2) autowiring the repository directly

Do both approaches behave in the same way? What is the difference between using the Repository directly versus using the Repository from within a service?

Repository:

```
package  com.me.repository;

import com.me.myentities.MyEntity;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;


public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {
}
```

Service:

```
package  com.me.service;
import   com.me.entities.*;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import  com.me.repository.*;
import javax.annotation.Resource;

@Service
public class MyService {

@Resource
private MyEntityRepository myEntityRepository ;

public void update(MyEntity myEntity)
{
    myEntityRepository.save(myEntity);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Either way you're working with the same sort of concrete Repository object, which is created by Spring when the container loads. And if you don't do anything with scoping, you're working with references to the exact same object.

Do do the approaches work the same way? If the service does nothing but make a pass-through call to the delegate Repository, then it's not going to result in any different end behavior. And if this pass-through behavior is all the Service does, it doesn't have an inherent reason for existing.

Spring Data JPA provides standard ways to add custom behavior to the Repositories, or to restricting the behavior of the repository to a smaller set of methods. The Spring Data JPA documentation (while brief) provides demonstrations of these techniques.

The end result is the same but generally you'll find working directly with a Repository more concise.